# Python 2 modules with python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, virtualenv, informix

I want to use informixdb 2.5 which is an DB-API 2.0 compliant module in a python 3 environment.  My computer has both python 2.6 and python 3.6 installed.  I have created a new virtualenv for my code.

I have used pip install for informixdb in the 2.6 environment and tested it and everything works tickety-boo.

I cannot work out how to reference the 2.6 version of the module in my 3.5 virtualenv.

I tried to use pip-install to just load it into the 3.5 environment but that fails ( it has the code "(34*3600L)" in it so clearly is not python 3 compatible).

I downloaded the source from sourceforge and tried to compile it but that also failed (errors locating the correct python headers).

I'm struggling.  Does anyone know if :
a) there is python 3 version of the module (and where) 
or 
b) Is this possible (and how) 
or 
c) am I completely barking mad and there is a better solution to accessing an informix database rather than through this module (I thought of using pyodbc, but thought if there is a specific module it would be better than using a generic odbc function).

Many thanks,

Comment: Generally you shouldn't expect to be able to use a Python 2 module with a Python 3 interpreter, if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you are trying to use this library: 
[informixdb 2.5](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/InformixDB)

This library is old and does not support python3.

If you need to work in python3 with IBM Informix db you can try another library called `python-ibmdb` available from here: [python-ibmdb](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think this is the right answer but after two days of struggling I cannot make it work.  I am running python 3.6 with informix 12.1 on Centos 6.8.
Everything is on the same machine.  I have the informix client SDK loaded.  I have the ibm data server package installed.

Comment: After a week I finally made it work.  It is not well documented.  The answer is you need a new entry for drsoctcp in your sqlhosts file with a new port number & a new matching server alias in your database configuration file.  Install the IBM Data Server Package (i.e. non-python) and ensure it's include directory is in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.  THEN you can install python-imdb.  Once complete you can use a connection string like :
DATABASE=xxx;UID=xxxx;HOST=<hostname> ;PROTOCOL=tcpip;PORT=<from sqlhosts>;PWD=xxxxx;

Answer (score 1):

you may try using PythonIfxDB (https://github.com/ifxdb/PythonIfxDB).
Should compile and 'work' with both 2.6 and 3.5

Comment: Many thanks for this suggestion.  The package looks encouraging and is very recent.  Unfortunately the build only works on Windows.  Currently there is no linux build (which is the paltform I'm using)

Comment: I haven't  tested it completely. but I can build it on my Linux box and it connects to my IDS server fine. But, it may need some attention and some of the tests are failing (and are not prepared for 3.x ).  Linux build instructions/setup is the next thing in the pipeline ;)

Comment: If you're involved in the development of PythonIfxDB, you should probably state as much in your answer — full disclosure and all that.

Answer (score 0):

If the module is available for both versions, then you need to install the module for python3 using python3-pip

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

Then install the modules with `python3-pip install module_name`